# Substitute all occurrences of pattern with first matched group

Tags: text-processing, vim, regular-expression

I have to go from this:

```
text match$something_here and match$xxx blablabla
text match$something_else_here and match$xxx blablabla
...
```

to this:

```
text match$something_here and match$something_here blablabla
text match$something_else_here and match$something_else_here blablabla
...
```

So I need to change, for every line in my file, the `xxx` after the 2nd occurrence of `match$` with whatever is after the first occurrence of `match$`.

Comment: What if there is third `match$` in the line?

Comment: Luckily, that's not the case in my file, at least for now. However, I think the answers provided can be adapted to that scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/match\$\zs\(\w\+\)\(.*match\$\)xxx/\1\2\1/
```

#### Explanation

- `match\$\zs`: anchor the match at the first `match$`; I use `\zs` to start the match after that, to avoid yet another capturing group
- `\(\w\+\)`: capture the text after the first occurrence of `match$`
- `\(.*match\$\)`: capture what's after that, up to the second occurrence of `match$`, and capture that as we want to keep it
- `xxx`: match what gets replaced

**Replacement**: The text after the first occurrence, then the text in between, then the first text again (replacing the `xxx`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/\(match\$\)\([a-zA-Z_]\+\)\([a-zA-Z ]\+match\$\)[a-zA-Z]\+/\1\2\3\2/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Using an `input.txt` of:

```
text match$something_here and match$xxx blablabla
text match$something_else_here and match$xxx blablabla
```

I get an `output.txt` of:

```
text match$something_here and match$something_here blablabla
text match$something_else_here and match$something_else_here blablabla
```

Comment: Your answer works almost perfectly in my PC, although it has a strange behaviour: I get 2 copies for every line (ie: 2 lines in input.txt, 4 lines in output.txt). I didn't research why would that be yet, maybe it has something to do with cygwin. I'll give the answer to Ingo since it works for Vim. Thanks again.

Comment: oh, sorry, i updated my answer to fix that.

Comment: This depends on a GNU `sed` and an ASCII locale.

Comment: Thanks for the infor, @mikeserv. I can tell you're right because this fails with the `--posix` flag to sed.  But I don't understand *why* - the sed man page doesn't do much to explain the non-posix features of GNU sed.

Comment: It's the `\+` metacharacters and similar - POSIX only specifies those for Extended regexp syntax, not for Basic regexp. And anyway, BRE can be more useful in scripts because it is easier to use information in variables without as much validation - you typically need only handle `\*$^[]` and then check whatever follows the backslash. Anyway, the `[A-Za-z0-9]` is the other culprit - the robust version is `[[:alnum:]]` and is probably what you should use instead - it is not less understandable but is more flexible

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/\v(match\$(\w+).*match\$)xxx/\1\2/
```

- \v very magical (we can use less \\)

Answer (score 1):

```sh
sed -e 's/\(match\)\([_[:alnum:]]*\)\(\(.*\)\n\)*/\1\
/2;tc' -e b -e :c -e 's//\1\2\4\2/'
```

The above sequence will always handle only the first and second occurrence of `match` on a line - regardless of how many there may be on a line.

It works by doing the the first `s///`ubstitution on the `s///2`cd occurrence of the pattern, then, if the substitution `t`ests successful, `b`ranching to the `:c`ontinue label, or, if not, `b`ranching out of the script.

So when there is a second match of the pattern, the pattern is repeated for the 2cd `s///`ubstitution command. But when there isn't the lines are printed as usual.

The important thing is the `\(\(.*\)\n\)*` subexpression. The subexpression matches only a null string for the first `s///2` command because a `\n`ewline can only occur in a `sed` pattern space as a result of an edit. But when the pattern is repeated the `\(\(.*\)\n\)*` matches any/all characters occurring between the two `match`es because the previous `s///`ubstitution inserted a `\n`ewline when replacing `[_[:alnum:]]*`. And so the same repeated pattern can mean two different things depending on its context in the script.

While the above version *should* work as written for any POSIX `sed` *(emphasis on **should** - many `sed`s don't conform to repeated subexpression standards)*, w/ GNU `sed` you can write it a little shorter:

```sh
sed -E 's/(match)(\w*)((.*)\n)*/\1\n/2;T;s//\1\2\4\2/
' <<\IN
text match_something_here and !m!atch_xxx blablabla
text match_something_here and match_xxx blablabla
text match_something_else_here and match_xxx blablabla
text match_something_here and match_xxx blablabla match_xxx blablabla
text match_something_else_here and match_xxx blablabla match_xxx blablabla match_xxx blablabla
IN
```

...The `<<\IN` through `IN` bit are just a here-document input so I can demonstrate how it works - you should probably use `<input_file` in its place. Also note that I changed your `$something` and `$xxx` for `_something` and `_xxx` because it is my understanding that those dollar-signs should not actually be included in the replacement pattern but will be substituted in for something else. If true, then you can keep the `\w*`ord escape there, or, If you do want literal dollar signs included, then you should still define your own character class and add it like: `[$_[:alnum:]]*`.

Notice that the `tc' -e b -e :c -e` is shortened to - with GNU `sed` - just a `T`. Whereas portably the `t`est resulted in a successful substitution `b`ranching over the point where unsuccessful lines `b`ranched away, with GNU `sed` you can `T`est for unsuccessful results - which directly branches them away and the only lines left still executing the script at that point are those which *did* successfully substitute the second match pair for a `\n`ewline.

In any case, *(depending on the `sed`)* either of the above will print:

```
text match_something_here and !m!atch_xxx blablabla
text match_something_here and match_something_here blablabla
text match_something_else_here and match_something_else_here blablabla
text match_something_here and match_something_here blablabla match_xxx blablabla
text match_something_else_here and match_something_else_here blablabla match_xxx blablabla match_xxx blablabla
```

Comment: Didn't work in cygwin at least: `$ sed -e 's/\(match\)\([_[:alnum:]]*\)(\(.*\)\n\)*/\1\2;tc' -e b -e :c -e 's//\1\2\4\2/' input.txt` gave the error message: `sed: -e expression #1, char 48: unterminated `s' command`.

Comment: @Juan - You didn't put it all in...? It needs to be `s/\(match\).../\1\<newline>/2...` - see?

Comment: I tried that too, but I get another error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 48: Unmatched ) or \)`

Comment: @Juan - that's my fault. A typo - I forgot a backslash - for what it's worth you can do the same thing w/ GNU `sed` like `sed -E "s/(match)([_[:alnum:]]*)((.*)\n)*/\1\n/2;tc;b;:c;s//\1\2\4\2/"`